# Closing modal from iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

I'm making an app that evaluates JavaScript inside `WKWebWiew`. My problem is that inside my `webView`, there is displayed a modal, which has only it's id = modal-form. How do I close it using JS?

What I have tried was for example something like: `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('modal-form').setAttribute(\"style\", \"display:none\");")`, but it doesn't work as it should.
Without Swift code it looks like: `document.getElementById('modal-form').setAttribute("style", "display:none");`
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementByClass` is not a method that exists on the JavaScript runtime (or, at least, it's not "native"). It should be `getElementsByClassName`, which returns an array and then you grab everything from that array.

If your modal is your only element of that class, it should get hidden as expected using:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-form');
elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
});
```

Or shorter:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('modal-form').forEach(function(e) { e.setAttribute('style', 'display: none') });
```

Finally, for your `WKWebView`, this should work:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName('modal-form').forEach(function(e) { e.setAttribute('style', 'display: none') });")
```

It should be a lot better if that particular modal had a unique `id` and reference it using `document.getElementById()`. `id`s are unique for HTML.

Comment: I have written by mistake `.getElementByClass` but I have tried `.getElementById`, because, as I mentioned, I have only this modal div id. Sorry for inconvinience

Comment: @mcgtrt if you show us the relevant part of your HTML it would be a lot easier to help you :)

Comment: It's not my html, I'm getting it from chrome inspector from a website I devastate :D It's a `<div class="Modal modal in active" id="modal-form" data-current-step="1" style="display: block; padding-left: 0px;">`